# Could the \include{} command be used in a knitr .Rnw file?

Tags: r, include, knitr, rstudio

Using \include{} usually works, unless there are code chunks in the file to be included:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% \include{test.tex}
\include{test.Rnw}  
\end{document}
```

with test.tex or test.Rnw define e.g. by

```
<<echo=TRUE,eval=TRUE>>=
plot(cars)
@
```

won't display the cars plot. Is there some chance to find a way to bypass that trouble?

Thanks,
Julyan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include .Rnw file with [child](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/).

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<test, child='test.Rnw'>>=
@

\end{document}
```

were test.Rnw contains:

```
<<echo=TRUE,eval=TRUE>>=
plot(cars)
@
```

Comment: Waouh, excelent, thanks a lot EDi! It is indeed a demo on knitr website, shame on me...